# Postgresql c# notify trigger does not send notification on update to c# insert, delete works

Tags: c#, wpf, postgresql

I am using notifications sent from postgresql database, insert notification works fine, but my update insert does not send message when buffer table data is changed and I can't understand why maybe you can figure it out I am out of luck here :(

```
var conn =
            new NpgsqlConnection(
                "xxxx");
        {
            conn.Notification += OnNotification;
            conn.Open();
            var command = new NpgsqlCommand("listen mymessage;", conn);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        };
```

_

```
public void OnNotification(object sender, NpgsqlNotificationEventArgs e) 
    {
        if (Application.Current.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        {
        }
        else
        {
            if (e.AdditionalInformation == "Duomenys ideti") // insert notification
            {
              // code which works.
            }
```

_

```
if (e.AdditionalInformation == "Duomenys atnaujinti") // update notify (does not work)
            {
                this.Close();

            }
```

Postgresql trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION buffer_notify_insert()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
PERFORM pg_notify('mymessage', 'Duomenys ideti');
RETURN NULL;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION buffer_notify_insert()
OWNER TO postgres;

CREATE TRIGGER buffer_notify_insert_trigger
AFTER INSERT
ON buffer
FOR EACH STATEMENT
EXECUTE PROCEDURE buffer_notify_insert();
```

And update trigger which is not working but data in column is changed.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION buffer_notify_update()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
PERFORM pg_notify('mymessage', 'Duomenys atnaujinti');
RETURN NULL;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION buffer_notify_update()
OWNER TO postgres;

CREATE TRIGGER buffer_notify_update_trigger
AFTER DELETE
ON buffer
FOR EACH STATEMENT
EXECUTE PROCEDURE buffer_notify_update();
```

Comment: Just a typo: `AFTER UPDATE` in the fourth line from the end.